# Using fitdistr in the MASS library

Tags: r

I am trying to use the fitdistr function, and have been reading the walkthough "Fitting Distributions with R". I can follow the outlined examples, with the 'dummy data', but my problem arises when I try to run my actual data with this function. 
I believe the problem is due to the presence of headers in my data, since I am constantly getting the same error. For example, if I run my data (2 columns with headers), through for the 2nd column:

```
fitdistr(data$col2,"gamma")   
'x' must be a non-empty numeric vector'
```

I have tried removing the header from my file and trying the function on all of my data (unbinned), which also resulted in the same error.

Next, I tried removing the header, and only having the column of data that I want to run the function on in the data file. This does run properly.

Please note that for my data, the 2nd column is what I am interested in running. But I have used the first column of data to sort the 2nd column into 20 different groups, so I do need the first column in the dataset. I can easily delete the headers and run the fitdistr() in a separate code (since I have been using headers to call columns thus far), but I cannot see how I could run this function with only one column of data, and still have that data binned properly. My first instinct is to bin the data in excel, then have 20 different, 1 column data sets to run through the function. This seems tedious, so any tips on how I can perform this function with my dataset intact is greatly appreciated.

As requested here is a sample of my data:

```
> dput(head(Diam_Str))
structure(list(Diameter = c(0.03, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05
), Strength = c(0.2, 0.2, 1.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3)), .Names = c("Diameter", 
"Strength"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

So I have 20 groups, based on diameter size. For each group I am looking at the distributions of strengths seen.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data into your question, using `dput(head(yourdat))`? The specifics of the data seem central to the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the first row of your dataset is being read in as data instead of a header, and when you try to run fitdistr on the entire column it's treating it as a character vector instead of numeric.

If you're reading in your data with the read.csv or the like, try adding the option 
header=T.

```
data = read.csv("file.txt", header=T)
```

You can verify a column is a numeric vector with

```
class(data$col2)
```

If this is the of type character, then there's probably a bad value in your input file somewhere.

If you think your data is ok, you can try

```
fitdistr(as.numeric(data$col2),"gamma")
```

And any bad values will be replaced with NA's

Comment: The 'as.numeric' seemed to have cleared that up for me. Thanks!

Comment: The second argument to `read.csv(file, header=TRUE)` is superfluous. That is the default. And if there were a character value in what was supposed to be numeric the class would not be "character", but rather "factor" since stringsAsFactor is TRUE by default. `typeof` would then return `integer` which would be misleading but that is the `typeof` of a factor vector. Best paractice would be to use colClasses.